# Using the jquery UI icons locally

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to be able to use a jquery icon in my js file. I was importing the UI js like :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

But I need to have it locally in my folder, so I downloaded the js and now it is:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

But this cause my icon not to load at this part of my code:

```
icons: {primary: "ui-icon-folder-open"},
```

I need this ui-icon-folder-open icon, where do I get this jpg image, and how do I call this?

Comment: Where is the CSS? That file has the url of the icon sprite.

Comment: Quick downloads: Stable - click Stable -  https://jqueryui.com/download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the jQuery UI CSS is looking for the icon in `images/[spriteName].png`. (The images directory should be in the same directory as the css.)

You can download jQuery UI (inclusive of JS, CSS, images, and demos) at http://jqueryui.com/download/.

A list of icon classes can be found in the docs here: http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/

Comment: How should i link to that folder in the imports section at the beginning of the html page? so the folder name is jquery-ui-1.10.4 and i put it inside /src

Comment: @JennyC Wherever the css file is referenced, (e.g., `www.example.com/src/jqueryui.min.css`), the `images` directory should be next to it. (e.g., `www.example.com/src/images/`) jQuery UI is written to automatically use the images from that location relative to the CSS file. You do not need to reference the images from the `<head>`.

Comment: Ok so I found the image of the icon, should I just put that img in the scripts folder where I stored the .css file?

Comment: @JennyC Use `/scripts/images/[iconFile].png`.

Answer (score 1):

You need the resources (like icons) as well so download the entire package from here:

[http://jqueryui.com](https://jqueryui.com/)

and then extract it into your local folder.

Comment: after downloading it and extracting it, icons: {primary: "ui-icon-folder-open"}, will work?